# How to merge 2 FirebaseListObservables into one observable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, ionic3

I have 2 Firebase lists:

- publicItems which contains 4 items
- privateItems which contains 2 items

I'd like to pull from both these lists and combine them into one observable.

To do this, I'm trying to use *merge*:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';

items: Observable<any[]>;
this.items = this.af.list('/privateItems').merge(this.af.list('/publicItems'));
```

And then in the view:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">item.title</li>
</ul>
```

However, this has the effect of only displaying the 4 public items.

Is *merge* the right tool for this?  How would I go about merging 2 FirebaseListObservables into 1 Observable that can be displayed together?

Comment: It is correct. Can you try `Observable.merge( ___ ,  ____ ) ` . Also try `this.af.list('/privateItems').do(console.log).merge(this.af.list('/publicItems')).do(console.log)`

Comment: Using Observable.merge( __, __) has the same effect.  It seems that whichever observable is second is "overwriting" the other.  For example, if I swap the call to privateItems with publicItems then it only displays the 2 private items. @Skeptor

Comment: did you try second statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.items = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.af.list('/privateItems'),
    this.af.‌​list('/publicItems'),
    (privateItems, publicItems)=> {
      console.log(privateItems); 
      console.log(publicItems); 
      return [...privateItems, ...publicItems]
    }
);
```

OR

```
this.items = this.af.list('/privateItems')
   .flatMap(privateItems=> this.af.list('/publicitems')
        .map(publicItems=> [...privateItems, ...publicItems])
   );
```

**Update**

I got what was happening in your case . You are getting a stream of two responses :

```
-----[privateItems] -------- [publicItems]-----
```

So the this.items gets the first response value and then it gets overrides with the second response value . But for your requirement you need both of them together, so probably using `reduce` might help.

```
this.items = this.af.list('/privateItems')
       .merge(this.af.list('/publicItems'))
       .reduce((total,current)=>[...total,...current],[]);
```

Comment: Awesome that did the trick!  In theory should the merge have worked similarly?

Comment: It should , let me think the same using merge

Comment: Updated with my reasoning why it was failing for you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for resurrecting an old post, but here's my solution for combining a variable number of FirebaseListObservables:

```
let rooms = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3'];
let observables = rooms.map((room) => { return this.cs.getMessagesByRoomId(room) });

this.messages = Observable.combineLatest(
  observables,
  (...rooms) => {
    console.log('rooms',Array.prototype.concat(...rooms));
    return Array.prototype.concat(...rooms)
  }
);
```